# c# regexp , replacing only in part of text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text variable which can contain many (`(VAR=var_name`)).
I want to replace ((`VAR=var_name`)) by the var_name only in `src=` (so, no in `href=` for instance.

```
sText = "some text href=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY))\"
src=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY)) \" some text some text
href=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY))\"
src=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY))\" some text";
```

I want to get after replacing :

```
sText = "some text href=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY))\"
src=\"sometext**XXXX**sometext**YYYYY**\" some text some text
href=\"sometext((VAR=XXXX))sometext((VAR=YYYYY))\"
src=\"sometext**XXXX**sometext**YYYYY**\" some text";
```

Have you got an idea ?

JC

Comment: Why so many example "obfuscations"? Is it HTML? Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string srcPattern = @"src="".+?""";
string varPattern = @"\(\(VAR=(.+?)\)\)";

string result = Regex.Replace(sText, srcPattern,
    m => Regex.Replace(m.Value, varPattern, n => "**" + n.Groups[1].Value + "**"));
```

The first regular expression match the string src = "...". While the second regular expression replaces every statement in brackets on its value.

Comment: @JAL Sorry, I'm not native English speaker. I find it easy to write code, but it is difficult to write a description in English.